# Create Keyboard Macro to change modifier keys on Mac

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mac, apple

I use parallels to run windows on my MacBook Pro for one of the application at work that requires hotkeys (such as Alt + C, Alt + X, Alt + Q etc). To ease my process while using this app, I tried using the Parallels' Shortcuts setting to change "Command" to "Alt", which works fine most of the time, but tends to not register when I press "Command + Q" even when I switched out "Quit ____" to a different hotkey. So, my only ways to comfortably and reliably use that button are either (1) having my thumb go all the way to the "Option" button, which is a bit of a stretch OR (2) going to System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys > switching Command Key to Option Key AND Option Key to Command Key and switch back when I'm done.

Basically, I was wondering if I can create a keyboard Macro, maybe set it to F12 to automatically switch between those 2 settings I mentioned above (Command Key to Option Key AND Option Key to Command Key Vice Versa).

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Registering a command or a script to shortcut menu.

1. Swap Left Command (Super) key to Left Option (Alt) key.

Install setxkbmap by `sudo apt install x11-xkb-utils`

`setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_lalt_lwin`

This will swap ALT_L and Super_L

2. Register this command to your Shortcut items.

[image: shortcutreg1]

[image: shotcut reg1]

Now each time you press <kbd>F12</kbd> Command key and Option key goes into another or goes back to normal.